# How to roll back my project?

Tags: android, cordova

I try to test PhoneGap Social Sharing plugin for Android, https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.

try to install with this code;
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

and then;
$ cordova prepare

after that I lost all my project files, so bad luck i don't backup or use version control and no files in recycle bin.

anyone can help me to rollback my project ?

thank you from stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I usually do for getting the lost project is by pressing "ctrl+z". Usually it will undo whatever happened in the eclipse maintained that if the project is not clicked "Delete project from disk" checkbox. Hope this will work. If it doesn't, then use some recuva software to get the project file from that folder. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks :) god still love me. I still have my apk in my phone. so extract it and it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Smart Data Recovery tools for backup.

Comment: thanks Priyanka Minhas :) In this case I have .apk file in my phone, just use android assistant for backup to sdcard and copy to my laptop. Then rename .apk extension to .zip and extract it. All files still in assets folder.